# ReactJS TaildwindCSS - darkMode is always set to true

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I'm using TailwindCSS in React app and i'm trying to make dark mode using Tailwind, but bg is already set to dark even though value is false.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const App = () => {

    const [darkTheme, setDarkTheme] = useState(false);

    return (<div className= {darkTheme ? 'dark' : ''}>
            <div className="bg-gray-100 dark:bg-gray-900">
              App
            </div>
        </div>);

};
```

Comment: `const [darkTheme, setDarkTheme] = useState(true);` ?

Comment: @doğukan it's false, i want it to be dark when it's true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are likely using the wrong darkmode toggle setting in `tailwind.config.js`. By default, the `tailwind.config.js` is setup to use CSS's `prefers-color-scheme`. You want to manually toggle dark and light mode in your code.

Set `darkMode: 'class'` in order to toggle darkmode via your class name.

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/dark-mode

Comment: Thanks it worked. I was watching some tutorial and the guy didn't really do this in the video, maybe the video is outdated.